# How to mutate a list with a function in python?

Tags: python, function, mutable

Here's a pseudocode I've written describing my problem:-

```
func(s):
   #returns a value of s

x = a list of strings
print func(x)
print x #these two should give the SAME output
```

When I print the value of x in the end, I want it to be the one returned by func(x). Can I do something like this only by editing the function (and without setting `x = func(x)`)

Comment: Mutate the list then return it.

Comment: For example: `def func(s): s.append('test'); return s`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
func(s):
   s[:] = whatever after mutating
   return s

x = a list of strings
print func(x)
print x
```

You don't actually need to return anything:

```
def func(s):
    s[:] = [1,2,3]

x = [1,2]
print func(x)
print x # -> [1,2,3]
```

It all depends on what you are actually doing, appending or any direct mutation of the list will be reflected outside the function as you are actually changing the original object/list passed in. If you were doing something that created a new object and you wanted the changes reflected in the list passed in setting `s[:] =..` will change the original list.

Comment: Thanks...I tried it but it didn't work at first.....then I used a global variable any it worked :D ... thanks

Comment: @RitvikSharma,  the contents of the list passed in will be changed by whatever iterable is on the right hand side of the assignment

Comment: It is very hard to search something like `[:]`. It is very useful peace of code.

Comment: Could you update to show how each element could be incremented by one?

Answer (score 13):

That's already how it behaves, the function *can* mutate the list

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c'] # your list of strings
>>> def add_something(x): x.append('d')
...
>>> add_something(l)
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Note however that you cannot mutate the original list in this manner

```
def modify(x):
    x = ['something']
```

(The above will assign `x` but not the original list `l`)

If you want to place a new list in your list, you'll need something like:

```
def modify(x):
    x[:] = ['something']
```

Comment: Remember to not assign to `x` in the function body. Otherwise `x` will become a local variable (an object in function's namespace) and will "cover" the argument passed to function.