# Why it require [:] (colon) in the function to mutate a list in global scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, copy

I was trying to find a solution to mutate a list by passing it to the function as an argument. For example:

```
def f(x):
    x = x*2
x = [9,8,7]
f(x)
print(x)
```

I want the result to be:

```
[9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7]
```

but it ended up like this:

```
[9, 8, 7]
```

and then I stumbled with this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31359713/13275449

The solution works wonderfully

```
def f(x):
    x[:] = x*2
x = [9,8,7]
f(x)
print(x)

[9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7]
```

My question is why we need the [:] ? I thought its the other way around, If we dont want to mutate the original list, we put [:] after it to copy it. But this one seems to be the opposite. It probably has something to do with global and function scope. I tried to use the pythontutor but still confused.

Thank you!

EDIT: semicolon -> colon

Comment: That is not a semicolon.

Comment: Did you forget to return it from the function? Note that in the first case you're just reassigning the variable x to something else (x * 2 creates a new list).

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say: this behavior is caused by function scope and global scope. Just to be clear, let's call `local x` to x inside the function and `global x` the other one. You pass `global x` value as parameter to `f` function, then using its values you're creating a new variable `local x`, the second one is not relating to the first one because it just exits inside the function and you won't be able to call it outside of it, you won't facing this confusion if you rename the `local x` as `y` as follow:

```
def f(x):
    y = x*2
    print(f'Inside function: {y}')
x = [9,8,7]
f(x)
print(f'Global x: {x}')
```

Output:

```
Inside function: [9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7]
Global x: [9, 8, 7]
```

The other hand, with `x[:]` you actually point to `global x` and that's the reason why you can print its value otherwise using `y` instead of `local x` you'll get an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File [file_name], line 6, in <module>
print(f'Global x: {y}')
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Answer (score -1):

Well this is concept of shallow copy and deep copy passing a list[:] like this will create a [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#shallow-vs-deep-copy) of the list and assign all the references of original list to the new copy created. Refer the docs for more details i have added a link to it.
Let me know if this helps brother!!!!.

Comment: thanks. Im still confused, why it is required to put [:] on x to mutate?

Comment: well it is because if you won't do that only value of an object will be altered and it will be only visible in that function scope and will not get reflected in actual object. But when [:] this is put it creates and object and it is altered.
Try playing with slicing of mutable and immutable objects it will get clear