# rewrite a fuction to return a mutated list

Tags: python, list, function, mutation

Hey (: I have to rewrite the code to return a mutated list

original code of the function

```
def times(l, n) :
    l_original = l
    
    for i in range(2, n+1) :
        l_original = l + l_original
    
    return l_original
```

my attempt to make it mutated:

```
def times_mut(l,n): 
    l1= l
    for _ in range(2,n-1):
        l.extend(l1)
l = [1,2,3]
times_mut(l,6)
print(l)
```

So my idea was to change the orignal list over and over or how exactly do I change the list into a mutated one ?

The expected output should be l*n.

Comment: For the record, you haven't actually asked any question other than "does it make sense"

Comment: Its unclear what outputs you expect

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it's good practice in Python to mutate OR return, but not both. That said, you were correct to remove the `return`.

Secondly, the problem here is how you use `extend`, which mutates the list along with `l1`, which is the copy of your original list.

If you run your code and print `l1` in the loop for debugging:

```
def times_mut(l,n): 
    l1= l
    for _ in range(2,n-1):
        print(l1) # debugging
        l.extend(l1)
l = [1,2,3]
times_mut(l,6)
print(l)
```

You will see that `l1` changes like so:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

even though you don't actually change it. That's because `l1` is a "shallow" copy of `l`, meaning that it points to the same place in memory. As a result, any change you make on `l` it will also appear in `l1`.

Why does this not happen in the original code? Because `l_original = l + l_original` creates a new list and stores is in the local variable `l_original` while the built-in functions like extend, append etc mutate the object.

I would advise that you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/9936645), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359652/how-to-mutate-a-list-with-a-function-in-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027694/correct-style-for-python-functions-that-mutate-the-argument) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748158/why-does-not-the-operator-change-a-list-while-append-does).

---

Furthermore, a simple solution would be to use `copy.deepcopy`, which basically copies the content of `l` and stores it on a new memory space like so:

```
import copy

def times_mut(l,n): 
    l_original=copy.deepcopy(l)

    for iii in range(2,n+1):
        l.extend(l_original)

l = [1,2,3]
times_mut(l,6)
print(l)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```